# In XSL how to you make a block take up a whole page?

Tags: pdf, xslt, pdf-generation, apache-fop

In xsl / fop how do you make a block take up exactly the whole page ?

Is there something like height = 100%?

I want the first page of my pdf to contain a block with dynamic summary that can be a couple of lines only so I don't want the rest of the pdf blocks to be come up on the first page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to insert a page break after the relevant block:

```
<fo:block break-after='page'/>
```